# gridbagconstraints not working

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I am using gridbaglayout to show a JLabel (number of thumbnails ) and some thumbnails whenever I add the thumbnail to the Jpanel with gridbaglayout it shows up in the center ignoring gridy values. The gridx values are working correctly but gridy values are completely ignored...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;


public class grid {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    private JLabel a = new JLabel("Welcome to PhotoAlbum55");

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public grid() {

        createAndShowGUI();

    }

    private void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {

        SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
        pane.setLayout(layout);

        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, a, 60, SpringLayout.WEST, pane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, a, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, pane);       
        a.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, 20));
        pane.add(a);

        JPanel photoPanel = new JPanel();
        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        photoPanel.setLayout(gbl);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        JScrollPane photoScroll = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS); 
        photoScroll.setViewportView(photoPanel);
        pane.add(photoScroll);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.ipadx = 15;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        JLabel photo = new JLabel();        
        Image img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg").getImage();
        Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance(50, 50,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);  
        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon(newimg); 
        photo.setIcon(newIcon);

        gbl.setConstraints(photo, gbc);                                 
        photoPanel.add(photo);

        JLabel photo1 = new JLabel();       
        Image img1 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Lighthouse.jpg").getImage();
        Image newimg1 = img1.getScaledInstance(50, 50,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);  
        ImageIcon newIcon1 = new ImageIcon(newimg1); 
        photo1.setIcon(newIcon1);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.ipadx = 15;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;


        gbl.setConstraints(photo1, gbc);                                    
        photoPanel.add(photo1);







    //  photoPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 900));
        photoScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));


        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, photoScroll, 60, SpringLayout.WEST, a);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, photoScroll, 100, SpringLayout.NORTH, a);


    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() { // Creating the GUI...

        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("PhotoAlbum55");

        // Set up the content pane.
        addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(690, 622);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                try {

                    new grid();
                }

                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both images are on the same y co-ordinate so the application is behaving as intended. On the other hand, the x co-ordinates differ so you need to set

```
gbc.weightx = 1;
```

for them to be positioned. If you need to add images to the top of the panel, they will need to be *anchored* there and set the weight along the y axis:

```
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
gbc.weighty = 1;
```

Comment: that didn't make any difference I won't to add the images at the top of the Jpanel not in the middle. I don't know why they are in the middle..

Comment: there are at the top now but centered and I also have to add the Jlabel to show how many thumbnails there are. So the Jlabel first then all the thumbnails..

Comment: Which label? Is is already added? Please update your question with exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: it is very basic I need to how many thumbnails there are and the thumbnails itself. At the top of the Jpanel there will be JLabel and below the Labels there should be the thumnails simple as that

Comment: You can add your label at `gridy` = 0 and images at `gridy` = 1